# How to call a method in a loop and overwrite the variable?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a loop that will output the square root of 100 then save that number and call the square root method on that number and so on and so on. An example of the output should look like this:

```
Start with 100
10 
3.1623
1.7783
1.3335
1.1548
...
```

How can I fix this current code to do this?

```
double A = Double.valueOf(100);
    double B;
    for(int z = 0; z<5; z++){
        B = Math.sqrt(A);
        System.out.println(B);
```

Comment: `A = Math.sqrt(A);`

Comment: Side note:  why `double A = Double.valueOf(100);`?, That just a long way of saying  `double A = 100;`,

Answer (score 4):

Assuming I understand your question, just update `a` (use `a` not `A`) in your loop (and you don't need `b`). Like,

```
double a = 100;
for (int z = 0; z < 5; z++) {
    System.out.println(a);
    a = Math.sqrt(a);
}
```

Comment: The answer above shows that you can assign `variable` to `Math.sqrt(variable)`, without using a different variable.

Comment: Unlike “algebra”, where `A = sqrt(A)` only has solutions `1` and `0`, programming always you to change the value of variables in the statement.  `A` was 100 when the statement starts, and becomes 10 when it has ended.